# What is the link between g-recaptcha-response one time token and deciphered audio text?

Tags: javascript, websites

They are multiple reports of recaptcha v2 bypass. Most of the time, the explanation is neural networks services provided by Google or ɪʙᴍ.

But there is something I am failing to understand : for most captcha (and including recaptcha v1) the manually deciphered text is sent directly to the server inside an ʜᴛᴛᴘ header. But with recaptcha v2, response sent to sever looks like :

```
g-recaptcha-response:03AJpayVEtSKNOXg7TJwMkmxzLA_HrnWMKm6p0ox6W6hhMcw3Bzxab8ariLgg8Q8wXpUcF8HLkhAd1ixXgNvBDde5ggVXidl3NuHSQcnP4QqJkVvWZ2s4_CQ1lHTw6oNEqXyiBuS3CkiHBhoB5akijJ6ld115K_OWZo6mfB4xz_-I2P36fVqT9VzEUz26wrauN9QZuC6lh80mf-fkxqCPmNYSOcMrHxR33Flby05gzo5cD1B-2FucaoFP11p2svvZrWC_vAjz5bGOzW0DufM2kkdtLIlhzl9GBzm_chyirSJItHGdz0bMuxDYZkRKY8c4gXUmzT09VEgivi032zZnNXtrVA04gXF5yE0tAtnGTwi31hMdzumPoc6GdLdIbvfbXgdyndocCLIph-j9T8ePf3JO8Jfcf6BNcmUKT2SrhZjIAPUOZV2Mg7Qua_s4zNHYx1-NE8zoe9SG-VxuPbx2sjR32ce4oapa6VA
```

even with an audio to text sample. Whatever the method claimed to be used, I am still failing to understand the link between `g-recaptcha-response` http header and human created data.

Recreating the `g-recaptcha-response` one time token seems to be a requirement for all bypass methods.
So what is the link between the one time token and a deciphered audio text for example ?

Comment: Obviously, several peoples successfully reversed engineered it…